# Getting click event handlers set up for multiple tables

Tags: javascript

I am making a test site where I will be displaying 4 tables (tables: A, B, C and D). The user will be able to click on any table rows and view a piece of information in an alert box (for now). What I am struggling with is setting up the click event for these tables. For instance, it takes two clicks for me to get a click event to fire and show the alert box, this happens in every table.

this is how i have my logic set up:

```
<!--Table A-->
<table id="table-A" class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                Table 1
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td onclick="AddRowHandler('table-A')">
              Info 1
              </td>
              </tr>

               <tr>
              <td onclick="AddRowHandler('table-A')">
              Info 2
              </td>
              </tr>

               <tr>
              <td onclick="AddRowHandler('table-A')">
              Info 3
              </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
...Same structure for tables B, C and D...

<script>
function AddRowHandler(tableID){
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var currentRow = table.rows[i];

      var createClickHandler =
        function (row) {
          return function () {
            var cell = row.id;
            alert(cell + " was clicked!");
            };
          };
        };
      currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
}
</script>
```

My question is, how do I set my click events properly, and, is there a more efficient way to do so? This last thought stems from the possibility of more tables being added.

Comment: you want that if someone clicks on row, show the data inside this row in `td` right ?

Comment: will there always be one `td`in each row ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey correct on both accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better add click handlers on `tr`s and get the `textContent` (I am assuming there is data only in `td`s).

```js
var el =  document.getElementById("data")
function AddRowHandler(ref){
   el.textContent = ref.textContent
}
```

```css
#data{
  padding : 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-A" class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                Table 1
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr onclick="AddRowHandler(this)">
              <td >
              Info 1
              </td>
               <td >
              Info 2
              </td>
              </tr>

               <tr onclick="AddRowHandler(this)">
              <td >
              Info 2
              </td>
              </tr>

               <tr onclick="AddRowHandler(this)">
              <td>
              Info 3
              </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          
          <div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: I got it to work and it shows the data in just one click, thanks!